# Get xpath under particular tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Am newbie to selenium (java).

I have to click on the menu item which is under `<ul>` tag as `<li>` items. I can able to get it with `//*[@id='MainMenu']/li[5]/span` xpath.

I do not want to hard code [5] of the list item, because item's position may change. It may not at 5th position all the time.

I wanted to get xpath for the particular item under particular tag with an id.

Edit:

This is how my html looks like. List item text will be loading dynamically.

```
<ul id="sfMainMenu" class="sf-menu ui-selectable">

    <li class="ui-selected ui-selectee">
        <span subnav="0" param="cmd=desk" filesrc="/Dashboard/Index"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-selectee"></li>
    <li class="ui-selectee"></li>
    <li class="ui-selectee"></li>
    <li class="ui-selectee">
        <span subnav="18" param="cmd=desk" filesrc="../myFile.aspx"></span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Kindly suggest the approach with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying this:

```
//*[@id='MainMenu']/li[normalize-space() = 'The text you want']/span
```

Though if you could show us what the HTML in question actually looks like, we can provide a more reliable answer. XPath doesn't have any concept of "visual text", so if you have some text that's hidden within the `li` you're trying to retrieve, that could be considerably trickier.

Comment: Good to know about "visible text". Let me try with your suggestion. Thank You.

Comment: Yes you are right JLRishe. I would have provide my HTML. Please look at my edited question above included my HTML.

Comment: I've never used Selenium and don't know if it's designed to handle dynamically loaded content, but can you show us what the HTML looks like after the content has loaded? (You can figure this out using Firebug or other browser debugging tools).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by using `filesrc` attibute of `span` tag in the list item.

Xpath is:

```
//span[contains(@filesrc, 'myFile.aspx')]
```

As my .aspx file will be the same for any page, so I used filesrc attribute which contains the actual file name and is the only file name in that html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(Text(),'Expected Text']")).Click();
```

Or you can avoid xpath all together by running a foreach loop on the relevant Class tag

```
 foreach (IWebElement e in driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("ui-selectee")))
        {
            if (e.Displayed && e.Text == "Expected Text")
                e.Click();
        }
```